# Using PHP mail function on XAMPP

Tags: php, email, xampp

I know this question has been asked  many times but after going through all of them i am still not able to send mails from  localhost. I have tried configuring my php.ini and sendmail.ini files but it still doesn't work.
I tried using smtp server ports 587 and 465 but none seem to work.

I have attached the screenshot of my .ini files.
Please Help!

[image: php.ini]

[image: sendmail.ini]

[image: sendmail.ini continued]

here is my php code :

```
   <?php 
    $from="From: jain.ayusch10@gmail.com";
    if(mail("gaganjain901@gmail.com", "Test Mail","THIS IS A TEST MAIL",$from)){
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "faliure";
    }

   ?>
```

Comment: why "\" in send mail path

Comment: Have you made sure you definitely have the mail server installed? Not just configured in `php.ini`.

Comment: I am just a beginner and installed the xampp server....just that.....:(

Answer (score 0):

You must try PHPMailer

> PHPMailer - A full-featured email creation and transfer class for PHP

[Here](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the php.ini is not enough. You would have to set up an `Mail Transport Agent`. For small projects it is better to use an existing mail sever over `SMTP` most of the time, since installing and configuring the mail server yourself will require lots of configuration, especially if you want to send HTML emails.

I recommend using **[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)** or **[Swiftmailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer)** for that purpose.

Other than that, if you have a hosting package your provider will most likely have a mail server installed and the mail function will work there. You just have to rethink the testing process.